# XSLT: copy attributes from child element

Tags: xslt

Input:

```
 <a q='r'>
   <b x='1' y='2' z='3'/>
   <!-- other a content -->
 </a>
```

Desired output:

```
 <A q='r' x='1' y='2' z='3'>
   <!-- things derived from other a content, no b -->
 </A>
```

Could someone kindly give me a recipe?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Easy.

```
<xsl:template match="a">
  <A>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*|b/@*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates /><!-- optional -->
  </A>
</xsl:template>
```

The `<xsl:apply-templates />` is not necessary if you have no further children of `<a>` you want to process.

Note

- the use of `<xsl:copy-of>` to insert source nodes into the output unchanged
- the use of the union operator `|` to select several unrelated nodes at once
- that you can copy attribute nodes to a new element as long as it is the first thing you do - before you add any child elements.

---

EDIT: If you need to narrow down *which* attributes you copy, and which you leave alone, use this (or a variation of it):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="(@*|b/@*)[
  name() = 'q' or name() = 'x' or name() = 'y' or name() = 'z'
]" />
```

or even

```
<xsl:copy-of select="(@*|b/@*)[
  contains('|q|x|y|z|', concat('|', name(), '|'))
]" />
```

Note how the parentheses make the predicate apply to all matched nodes.

Comment: Good but incomplete as states in question _"things derived from other a content, no b"_.

Comment: @Alejandro: You are right. Some more context on how to handle `<b>` would have been in order. @DevNull's answer covers that, though.

Comment: +1 for the Note on why parentheses are used to 'make the predicate apply to all matched nodes'

Answer (score 6):

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <A>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|b/@*|node()"/>
        </A>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="b"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<A q="r" x="1" y="2" z="3"><!-- other a content --></A>
```

Comment: Tip: It is not necessary (even counter-productive) to include XML declarations *with* encoding attributes with XML code samples here. You cannot anticipate which encoding files will be in when someone copies your sample.

Comment: True. It's part of my oXygen templates and I always forget to remove them. Thanks Tomalak.